# How to capture execution error (stderr connection) into a string variable?

Tags: r

With stdout connection we can use `[capture.output][1]` function. But what about error messages?

This will of course require some form of `try` block. But FAIK the `try` block doesn't provide a way to access the string of actual error messages that were repressed.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `tryCatch` and `conditionMessage`

```
tryCatch(stop("oops"), error=function(err) conditionMessage(err))
```

Provide a reproducible example for more help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `geterrmessage` to retrieve the last error message:

```
stop("Hammer Time")
Error: Hammer Time
geterrmessage()
[1] "Error: Hammer Time\n"
```