# Monitoring a shared variable with read write access by multiple threads in C++

Tags: c++, c++14

I am looking for a better implementation of the below code segment to minimize CPU usage. I have a variable that has read/write access for multiple threads and needs to be monitored as below.

```
while(true){
     mutex.lock();
     int flag = external_flag;
     mutex.unlock();
     if(flag == 3){
          break;
     }else if (flag == 4){   
          go to label;
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)?

Comment: Is the `external_flag` protected for concurrent writes outside of the code you are showing? If yes, why not removing the `flag` variable and compare `external_flag` directly with 3 and 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an atomic variable since that will be faster than a full-blown mutex and as well as likely lock-free. For instance,`std::atomic<int>` 
 or `std::atomic_flag` depending on what you are doing.

However, depending on what you are exactly doing in your code, you may want to use a condition variable like `std::condition_variable` to avoid spinning.

Comment: Also, OP shouldn't "hammer" the variable all the time.

Comment: @user4581301: No, that's something you can [do with R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15833667/1593077).